# Casting integer constant to a pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Is it UB to cast an arbitrary integer constant to a pointer to a object/function type (to use in unit tests for example)?

```
struct helper; //opqaue, creation the structure is complicated

struct my_struct{
   struct helper *h_ptr;
   char another_member;
};

static inline struct my_struct *create_my_struct(struct helper *h_ptr, char am){
    struct my_struct *m_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*m_ptr));
    m_ptr->h_ptr = h_ptr;
    m_ptr->another_member = am;
    return m_ptr;
}
```

I want to write unit test for it as follows:

```
uintptr_t helper_ptr = (uintptr_t) 2; //How about this?
char am = 'a';
struct my_struct *ms_ptr = create_my_struct((struct helper *) helper_ptr, am);
//do asserts
```

The thing that I'm not sure about is `(struct helper *) helper_ptr`. Is it UB? What if `(uintptr_t) 2` is not correctly aligned?

Comment: It is ok until you are going to dereference it.

Comment: @Sandro So the alignment is not an issue here. I was not sure about it. Thanks.

Comment: even if it is not correctly aligned, you should not face the problems if you don't dereference it.

Comment: @Sandro I agree about that, but unfortunately I will have UB when try to compare them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C11 Standard 6.3.2.3 Pointers, paragraph 5:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

So you can do it as long as you do not dereference it, and it is not UB, but whatever happens will depend on the platform.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. As you mentioned the casting is not UB by itself. But comparing two such pointers is UB unfortunately...

Comment: Well, comparing (for equality) is not itself the issue.  The issue is storing or reading back the value at all, as it might be a trap representation.

Comment: 6.5.8 is about the relational operators, not the equality-test operators (6.5.9).  The equality-test operators do not have the same limitation.  That's why I specified that equality testing is what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Acorn Actually 6.5.9, 6.5.8 is about relational operator.

Comment: @JohnBollinger But paragraph 6 of 6.5.9 specifies the limitation. We are stuck with `NULL` or array element/one past last array element.

Comment: No, @St.Antario, 6.5.9/6 simply specifies the conditions under which two pointers compare equal.  If those conditions are not satisfied then they compare unequal.  No UB arises (from that).

Comment: @JohnBollinger For equality comparison of those pointers, and whether it should return unequal or not, I opened this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764953/c11s-equality-operator-on-converted-pointers

Comment: @JohnBollinger Anyway using such pointers for test purposes (test for comparing equals) seems to be useless. We cannot guarantee the equality even if the pointers are gotten from the same values.

Comment: Agreed, @St.Antario.  So how about instead using a pointer that is known definitely to point to an object?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, it seems no another conforming choice.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is defined (if you don't dereference) even if the pointer isn't correctly aligned.

[6.3.2.3p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5)
Mentions the possibility of incorrect alignment for int-to-ptr conversions without seemingly attaching undefined behavior to it:

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously
>   specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be
>   correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
>   type, and might be a trap representation.

In contrast, [6.3.2.3p6](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6) says that *pointer-to-pointer* conversions that result in a misaligned pointer *are* undefined behavior. (The informal [J.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#J.2) appendix that lists undefined behaviors also only lists pointer misalignment arising from *pointer-to-pointer* conversions as UB).

(This would interestingly imply that any pointer-to-pointer conversion may be facilitated without UB by using an sufficiently sized integer (if it exists) as an intermediary.)

Comment: @Acorn I think 6.3.2.3p6 provides a useful contrast. But it's not like I missed _that_ from your answer so I posted mine -- I only saw yours after I posted mine (upvoted it too ;-)).

Comment: I concur, except for the last sentence, with the qualification that the standard explicitly allows such a conversion to produce a trap representation.  If it does, then the conversion itself still has defined behavior, but storing the result in an object does not.

Answer (score 0):

The whole memory mapped register harware level programming relays on it.

for example:

```
#define GPIO_Typedef *GPIOA (voaltile GPIO_Typdef *)0x40000300
```

and then we can dereference it accessing the register in the memory

```
 GPIOA -> MODER = .....
```

Comment: Of course that will always work (otherwise C is useless), but those are valid addresses; while OP is asking about arbitrary addresses that may not contain anything valid, or not even be a valid pointer address to being with.

Comment: This an arbitrary address. Isn't it?

Comment: Not really, it is an address that you carefully chose for mapping your hardware.

Comment: The address has to have some logic in it.  But using the pointers with the arbitrary addresses (which have no memory address sense) is used in most of the RTOSes to pass parameters in the pointers (to use queues with the pointer size only without the actuall memory for the data allocated)

Comment: Whether it works as expected for particular addresses with a particular implementation does not speak to whether the behavior is undefined as far as the language standard is concerned.

Comment: Read OP's question carefully: it is supposed to be a unit test using a completely arbitrary number, no hardware mapping here. Anyway, I think you are mixing concepts. Pointers that map hardware *are* valid addresses (and surely non-arbitrary); even if they don't point to the main memory.