# C's equality operator on converted pointers

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer

Coming from [Casting integer constant to a pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764405/casting-integer-constant-to-a-pointer-type/55764712)

From that question, we know from 6.3.2.3p5 (C11) that we can convert any integer into a pointer (i.e. it is not UB on itself):

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

Then, from 6.5.9p6, we have:

> Two pointers compare equal if and only if both are null pointers, both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object and a subobject at its beginning) or function, both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the address space.

So it seems we can apply the equality operator here with no UB (unlike the relational operators). Consider:

```
struct A;

int f(void) {
    struct A * a = (struct A *) 1;
    struct A * b = (struct A *) 1;
    return a == b;
}
```

Assuming there is no `A` object in `a`'s address `1`, one could argue that `f()` should return `false`, because no condition matches the above.

How is this refuted? Does "pointer to the same object" refer to addresses, even if no objects are there (not like the compiler could know, anyway)? Should we simply understand that it is implementation-defined since the previous results were already implementation-defined? Where does the standard specify this?

All major compilers return `true` for the above code, as one would expect.

Comment: What is "*Except as previously specified*" referring to?  That might be important.  Also, as far as Trap Representation is concerned, is it referring to the object supposedly pointed to, or is it referring to the pointer itself having trap representation perhaps as a result of misalignment?

Comment: They appeared to compare equal https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ca45c3b900ade34 even with `-O3`. Strange...

Comment: @ChristianGibbons That refers to the null pointer constant case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How is this refuted? Does "pointer to the same object" refer to
>   addresses, even if no objects are there

No, I don't think that would be a plausible reading.  If you stipulate that the pointer value is not a pointer to an object (and if it is not a null pointer) then an equality comparison of that (pointer) value with itself does not satisfy the "only if" condition of 6.5.9/6, and therefore the comparison must evaluate to 0.

But not so fast.  Who says that `(struct A *) 1` is not a pointer to an object?
Consider the Standard's definition of "object":

> **object**
>   region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of
>   which can represent values

([C 2011, 3.15/1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15p1))

Note that the definition is not inherently limited to objects that are allocated or declared by the program.  To the best of my knowledge, the standard nowhere limits the scope of the term in that way.  It does define means to allocate objects, but it does not specify that objects allocated in one of those ways are the only ones that exist.  Thus, implementations are free to interpret that pointer value as a pointer to an object, in which case the equality comparison may evaluate to 1.

It also might still *not* evaluate to 1, as despite the two pointers (presumably) having bitwise-identical representations, they are not necessarily considered pointers to the same object.

> (not like the compiler could
>   know, anyway)?

Of course the compiler could and should know.  It has to know in order to evaluate expressions such as you present.  The most straightforward approach -- and, not coincidentally, the most common -- is to interpret every non-null pointer value that is not a trap representation as a pointer to an object.

> Should we simply understand that it is
>   implementation-defined since the previous results were already
>   implementation-defined?

Being implementation-defined carries a requirement for conforming implementations to document their choice.  The behavior you're asking about may follow from the implementation-defined behavior of converting an integer to a pointer, but it is not implementation-defined itself.

> Where does the standard specify this?

It does not specify.  In principle, conforming implementations may differ on this point.  In practice, however, they're pretty consistent.

Comment: Note also the Committee response to [C defect report 260](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_260.htm), in which the Committee holds that "[Implementations] may also treat pointers based on different origins as distinct even though they are bitwise identical."  That could be taken as applying to the example case, so again, the standard does not specify.

Comment: In this [live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5ae33a9450bc2113) example however this is exactly the case. -O2 yields different addresses btw which is not really clear to me...

Comment: Which "this" is exactly what case?  And are you claiming that's inconsistent with this answer?

Comment: I meant two pointers with the same address  did not compare equal... no?

Comment: Yes, in that example, two pointers containing identical representations compare unequal.  But I'm uncertain what point you're trying to make with that.

Comment: That the example exhibits different behavior with different optimization levels does not prove that the code has UB.  The same can happen if it has behavior that is merely unspecified, as that code does.

Comment: The example I provided is not really related here and it seems to be a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61502). But it's still open.

Comment: "*Of course the compiler could and should know.*" The sentence between parenthesis referred to the previous one, i.e. that it is impossible, in general, to know whether a pointer points to an actual object or not (typically one does not even know the value of the pointer when compiling a equality comparison, e.g. it may come from a different TU).

Comment: About whether something is an object or not, it is very confusing. The standard talks about "one-past" objects in an array and similar stuff in several places to disallow some behavior, but then allows to assume arbitrary objects? Oh well :-)

Comment: Another comment on "*region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values*". What is a region of data storage? Because we could argue that `1` may not point to any storage that can actually represent values (in several interpretations: not paged, invalid address, not allocated...; and again, the compiler cannot really know in the general case). Also: if all addresses can potentially be regions of data storage that can represent values, we could further ask what is the point of that qualification? We can go very deep into the rabbit's hole I guess! :-)

Comment: @Acorn, your question and comments seem to be colored by the characteristics of specific implementations known to you and of the physical machines on which they run.  That's not so useful for interpreting the standard, whose semantics are defined in terms of an *abstract* machine, which itself is incompletely specified.  Implementations have considerable latitude in how they map the abstract machine to their target physical machine and environment.  The mapping is from standard to implementation, not the other way around.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Not at all. I am well aware of the abstract machine (and I have worked on "exotic" architectures, too), but the standard does not define well the terms here (and in many other cases). The standard is written after what compiler experts believe it is possible/reasonable/useful, not the other way around. So, even if the wording is supposed to be abstract (for good reason) and must be interpreted as such (after having been published), I find it is good to question its definitions to see if they should be improved.

Comment: That is why, here, in my opinion (or unless someone explains it) "*region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values*" does not really add much value to the standard (specially the second half of the sentence). By the way, don't get me wrong, you are very likely more knowledgeable than me on the C standard, and I don't mean to say your answers/comments aren't useful (they very much are); but every time we pull the "it-is-abstract" card, it is likely we have either found a potential improvement and/or it is not meant to be interpreted in such way.

Comment: It sounds like you would prefer the standard to place stronger or more specific requirements on implementations than it does, @Acorn.  There's nothing inherently wrong with that, but you should at least appreciate that there are reasons why it doesn't.  Among them are that C is specified in a way that can be implemented on a very wide variety of machines, including some that would undoubtedly feel alien to you, and that it wants to leave as much room as possible for optimization.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Agreed! I respect those decisions; it made a lot of sense back when they were made. However, I feel nowadays people want very clear & strict specs (which in many cases ends up meaning closer-to-actual-HW), for good reasons too. Also, there has always been the camp of "practical engineers" that don't appreciate the formality of the standard either when its abstractness and/or difficult wording ends up with non-portability between compilers/archs, defeating the purpose of why it was abstract in the first place. In C it's usually OK; in C++, this feels even more pronounced...

Answer (score 2):

**Constraint violation**

> An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the
>   result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an
>   entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation. C17dr §6.3.2.3 5

With `(struct A *) 1` code attempts the conversion. The result is *implementation-defined*, may lack *alignment*, ... might be a *trap*.

Next code tries to initialize `a` below.

```
struct A * a = (struct A *) 1;
```

Initialization constraints include:

> No initializer shall attempt to provide a value for an object not contained within the entity being initialized. §6.7.9 2

It is not defined that `(struct A *) 1` meets that constraint.

Comment: I'm having *great* difficulty accepting your application of 6.7.9.2.  From what I can see, the initializer is providing a value for the whole of `a`, which is utterly routine.  I don't think that provision has anything to do with limiting the value specified.  What it forbids is declarations like this: `struct { int a; } x = { .b = 1 };`, on account of the entity being declared, `x`, not having a member named `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Not every architecture allow the pointers to any possible integer value.  Not every architecture is able to keep a pointer that represents the location 1000 (or whatever integer), maybe because its assembly language miss such a feature.  The C language does not impose any representation for a memory location -- on some architectures the address 1000 may have no meaning.

A detailed discussion is [on the blog of Stefan Schulze Frielinghaus](https://stefansf.de/post/).  I quote from the article [Pointers are more abstract than you might expect in C](https://stefansf.de/post/pointers-are-more-abstract-than-you-might-expect/) -- here there is a detailed explanation where you can see a concrete example identical to yours, so:

> Note that the pointers p and q point to the same memory address. Still the expression p == q evaluates to false which is very surprising at first.

Comment: The OP's comparison certainly is not implementation *defined*, but it is implementation *dependent*.  The distinction is in whether conforming implementations are required to document their choice.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Can you provide a link in ISO9899 (or some other official paper) where I could find the definition of `implementation dependent` ?

Comment: In fact no, I can't.  The term "implementation-defined" is formally defined by the standard, but the term "implementation dependent" is just common language (but nevertheless a widely used term in this context).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, this is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because neither `a` nor `b` point to an object and (most likely) the converted values are not properly aligned.

This however should be OK:

```
struct A * a = (struct A *) 1;
struct A * b = (struct A *) 1;
return (int)a == (int)b;
```

Since you convert an integer to a pointer and back again to get the original value.

Comment: But what exactly in the standard makes it UB?